# Hiding/Deactivating the Close-Button in File-Menu

Tags: c#, word-2010

Our company is writing a word addin.

In some cases, our customers work in some sort of Kiosk mode, in which they shouldn't be able to close Word in any way. We're able to deactivate the close button (X) on the top right corner, however, our customers are still able to close Word over words File-menu.

Is there any way hiding/removing or deactivating the menu item in the file-menu, which closes word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messed around with it for some time now and figured it out myself.

You can disable the menu item inside your `Ribbon.xml`

```
<command idMso="FileExit" enabled="false" />`
```

If you use the `getEnabled`-attribute, you're able to decide whether to enable or disable it in your code (`Ribbon.cs`).

```
<command idMso="FileExit" getEnabled="MyMethod" />`
```